# Rails: Demarcating Users, Admins, etc. with Sessions, Cookies or Namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, namespaces

I'm getting my head around Rails & have a few high-level questions that generally revolve around users, their rolls and how to structure or lay out a new Rails app. I'm really just looking for different ideas (or validations on the uneducated guesses I've attempted below) and their pros & cons.

A new project will have **users**, **admins** and, let's call them, **stakeholders**.

Each of these are, obviously, people, and each of them needs to log in and will have different "rolls". I know there are many ways to approach this but I'm looking for the "Rails" way to take advantage of as much, so called, "Convention Over Configuration" as possible.

- **admin** has super powers and can see & go anywhere
- **stakeholders** can only make changes to their areas of the site
- **users** (maybe there's a better name as ALL roles are in a sense
  'users') can only view content
  created by the stakeholders and
  optionally comment on them.

So, how to handle this...

**Login:** use a single login form and then assign different rolls? or send users to one login and admins, to another, etc...? pros/cons? I guess maintaining one User class would be easier than splitting them up...but what about security?

**Routes:**

- To avoid nesting routes (which many advise against) I'd like stakeholders to ONLY see their own 'stake'. So when they log in they're immediately presented with their little area. Wondering if instead of /stakeholders/stakeholder_id/stakes/new maybe I could just have /stakes/new. How is this handled? In the User? In the Session? Cookie?
- And what about the Admins? I've seen examples of this roll moved to its own "namespace" *(I think?)* where all Admin tasks are prepended with /admin/... Is this common? Or is there a better way?
- And, lastly, what happens when a higher roll (`admin` or `stakeholder`) wants to 'share' a view or controller, or *any* code for that matter, used by a lesser roll (`user`)? if `admin` has its own controllers, models & views under `admin/` then is it appropriate to use `/stake/new` or do we need to also maintain a `/admin/stake/new`?

Sorry for my confusion & verbosity. Any help, or examples/documents, would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Recommend you search for authorization on railscasts.com, for one. You're asking some basic questions that are easily solved once you have a look at the many authorization libraries out there. Good luck.

Comment: I'm aware of authorization either home grown or **authlogic** or **devise**, etc... what I'm *not* aware of is how they relate to the structure of the app itself. now, i haven't *used* one, yet, so maybe that will become clear as I read each one's docs? or maybe there's a 'standard' overall approach used by all (Rails way) and I guess that's what I'm asking about...

Comment: play with them as fullware suggests.  It will become clearer once you do.  For stuff like stakeholders, it is dead simple to just scope your queries to only the current logged in stakeholder. ie just call @current_stakeholder.stakes.new, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "standard" way to handle authentication and authorization in ruby on rails. Usually I find that a gem based solution is the best way to go. Personally I use Devise and CanCan (hosted at github, google search will turn it up). See railscasts.com as suggested by fullware above for some great examples on implementation.

To you questions:

- CanCan handles authorization (what a user is allowed to do) where as Devise (or authlogic) handles authentication.
- The simplest way to handle roles is to add a boolean column to the user table for each role you want to define so in your example above there would be a boolean for admin, user and stakeholder. When you create your user you would want to automatically set the user field to true (this can be done with a before_save filter in your user model). Then when you need to give a user permissions simply set that role true.
- Once you have that setup configure CanCan to restrict based on those fields (see either the CanCan documentation or railscasts.com for how to do this).
- Security: you mentioned splitting admin and user functions and logins. This is an open debate for web developers, some prefer to do inline administration (where addition options simply appear in the "public" view) where as others prefer a completely separate admin interface with different credentials. The answer really depends on the needs of your application. From a security standpoint having a separate admin interface with its own credentials and located on a separate subdomain (ie admin.yoursite.com) is more secure because XSS is much more difficult (more info @ the security guide on guides-DOT-RubyOnRails-DOT-ORG)
- RE: the stakeholder "home page" I am not a 100% clear on whether `stakes` is a nested resource or something else. If it is a nested resource one option might be to use the :shallow routing option (see here: http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/9/7/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-shallow-routes)
- Your last point is the trickiest, im not clear on what you mean by "share code" with a user but the answer is probably to make your permissions system (Admin, Stakeholder, User) more advanced and have permissions linked to more actions like a permission to create something or view something. this would allow you fine-grained control. There are a number of role management plugins (try google for these) that might provide you this.

Sorry about not posting more links, as a new user I can't post more than one apparently.

Hope this helps.